# Floating View over UITableView in RootViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

In the main UITableView for a RootViewController.

How can I add a View over a RootViewControllers TableView, with its position relative to screen and not to TableView, so it doesn't scroll with it?

Note - it will be a progress bar showing new data for the table downloading progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help if you posted your code, but: you're presumably adding the `UITableView` to your RootViewController with something like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:myUITableView];
```

Just add your floating view in the same way (i.e. add it to your view controller, not to your UITableView). If you add it after you add the table view, it will already be "above" the table view. Otherwise you can bring it to the top with something like this:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myOverlayView];
```

Your overlay view should sub-class `UIView`, and it should set its own `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]` in order to make it transparent. In order to allow the user to continue interacting with the table view (which you presumably want to have happen), in your overlay subclass override `hitTest:withEvent:` and return the table view (instead of returning `self` which is the default behavior). This will pass all touches on to the table view underneath.

Comment: You can set userinteractionenabled to no and this passes all events to the underlying view, you don't need to override hitTest

Comment: @jrturton: yeah, that's a lot simpler than overriding hitTest.

Comment: Since I'm in my RootViewController class I have to write: `        [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:self.myOverlayView];`, but everything just working.